# Why during conversion to single I lost the point (13.5 becomes 135)?

Tags: c#, valueconverter

I use just simple code but I cannot understand the reason of mistake

```
Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToSingle("13.5"));

output 135
```

Why??

Comment: Most probably because of your locale in which the point is the thousands seperator

Comment: My *guess* is that your current thread's culture uses `.` as a thousands separator, not a decimal point... specify the invariant culture (e.g. `float.Parse("13.5", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)` if necessary.

Comment: CultureInfo.InvariantCulture solved the problem, thank you

Answer (score 6):

It seems, that `.` is a *thousands separator* (which is *ignored* during conversion) in your current culture; use `InvariantCulture`:

```
  Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToSingle("13.5", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
```

Comment: @Mikail: quite a typical problem, esp. for `Russian` (`ru-RU`) culture with `,` decimal separator (*comma*) and `.` thousand separator (*dot*)

Comment: Dmitry, yes it was really problem that I could not imagine. Mine was changed from American to Turkish.